# Firebase - Get field using variable as property

Tags: javascript, firebase, web

Im trying to get a field from a "doc.data" using a variable, the thing is that i want to reuse that function with different field names.

This is the code:

```
        btnsEditvalue.forEach((btn) => {
            btn.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
              try {
                propToEdit = e.target.dataset.prop;
                const doc = await getElement(e.target.dataset.id, col);
                const element = doc.data();
                console.log(element.propToEdit)
                editElement.value = element.e.target.dataset.prop;
                id = doc.id; 
              } 
              catch {
                console.log("error");
              }
            });
        });
```

The output is undefined, because "propToEdit" isnt a field in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try passing the dynamic key using the bracket notation, instead of the dot notation.

> Refer to javascript object [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

```
const element = doc.data()
const ELEMENT_KEY: string = 'propToEdit'
console.log(element[ELEMENT_KEY])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access fields dynamically with a custom name

```js
fieldName = "stringValue"
element[fieldName]
```

this does depend entirely on where `doc` from `doc.data()` is maintained

You can wrap it into a function as well, this will return the value or null.
You can swap null out with any other default value you want.

```js
function getField(fieldName, doc){
    return doc.data()[fieldName] || null;
}
```